# Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale with factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-factor

I got this data.frame

```
'data.frame':   935 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ IQ        : num  93 119 108 96 74 116 91 114 111 95 ...
 $ KWW       : num  35 41 46 32 27 43 24 50 37 44 ...
 $ educ      : num  12 18 14 12 11 16 10 18 15 12 ...
 $ exper     : num  11 11 11 13 14 14 13 8 13 16 ...
 $ tenure    : num  2 16 9 7 5 2 0 14 1 16 ...
 $ age       : num  31 37 33 32 34 35 30 38 36 36 ...
 $ married   : Factor w/ 2 levels "married","non-married": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ black     : Factor w/ 2 levels "black","non-black": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ south     : Factor w/ 2 levels "non-south","south": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ urban     : Factor w/ 2 levels "rural","urban": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ sibs      : num  1 1 1 4 10 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ brthord   : num  2 NA 2 3 6 2 2 3 3 1 ...
 $ meduc     : num  8 14 14 12 6 8 8 8 14 12 ...
 $ feduc     : num  8 14 14 12 11 NA 8 NA 5 11 ...
 $ lwage     : num  6.65 6.69 6.72 6.48 6.33 ...
 $ experclass: Factor w/ 5 levels "(0,5]","(5,10]",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 4 ...
 $ iqlevel   : Factor w/ 4 levels "50","75","100",..: 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 3 3 2 ...
```

drawing a ggplot like this works:

```
   p<-ggplot(data = wage)
  p+ geom_jitter(aes(x = educ, y = lwage, shape=married,
                col = black, size=IQ, alpha=0.1))
```

however not like this

```
   p<-ggplot(data = wage)
  p+ geom_jitter(aes(x = educ, y = lwage, shape=married,
                col = black, size=iqlevel, alpha=0.1))
```

the error occurs in geom_smooth, here's the full code

```
  load("C:/tmp/session08.rda")

  wage["iqlevel"]<-cut(wage$IQ, breaks=c(0,75,100,125,Inf), labels=c(50,75,100,125))

  # geom_jitter where col, size, etc define different representations/ axes
  p<-ggplot(data = wage)

  p+ geom_jitter(aes(x = educ, y = lwage, shape=married,
                    col = black, size=iqlevel, alpha=0.1)) +
  # a grid
  facet_grid(urban ~ experclass)+
  # setting the axis labels
  xlab("Education (Years)") + ylab("Log Wage") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Experimental\nCondition") 
  # setting the labels for the legend
  labs(shape="Martial Status", col="Ethnicity", size ="IQ") +
  # removing alpha from the legend and setting dots as the symbol of the size legend
  guides(alpha=FALSE, size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 20))) +
  # trying to draw a regression, without the confidence interval
  geom_smooth(se=F, method ="lm", color="black", fullrange=T, na.rm=T,
              aes(lwd=1, x = educ, y = lwage))
```

**EDIT:**

the session file containing wage:
[session08.rda](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3739296/session08.rda)

PS:
I need to set the factor levels, because the IQ levels should be custom

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you can provide a small, reproducible version of this issue.

Comment: ok, added the rda file containing the wage data, now the whole code should work (except for the last geom_smooth part)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lwd` isn't a valid `geom_smooth` aesthetic parameter. Set `size=1` outside of the aesthetic function like you do with `color="black"`.

Here's the documentation [link](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_smooth.html).

Comment: hahaha, I can't believe that created this obnoxious error! thanks a lot!